# Responsive but with break points

Tags: breakpoints

Is there anyway of making JSSOR responsive but with breakpoints instead of it making the items smaller on window resize.

In other words it shows 4 items at full screen then at a breakpoint of a resolution of 1200 it shows 4 items then another breakpoint 2 items then another break point 1 item but the items always stay the same size.

How it is at the moment it always shows 4 items or whatever you set in the script that just get smaller when resizing and this means that it ends up on my layout with a overhang of about 20px.

A breakpoints system is possible because another slider called [SLICK SLIDER](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) uses breakpoints but it is impossible to implement it into any page because it is not as novice friendly as JSSOR

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible by manual script.

You can reach the goal this way,

1. Wrap your slider in a container

   ```
   <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;>
       <div id="slider1_container" ...>
       ...
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Scale the slider to double width if screen width is less than or equal to a specified value (e.g. 480)

   ```
   function ScaleSlider() {
       var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
       var newWidth = bodyWidth;
       if(bodyWidth <= 480)
           newWidth * = 2;
       if (bodyWidth)
           jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(newWidth);
       else
           window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
   }
   ```